# Set that is a cutset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let X be a connected topological space. A cutset of X is a subset S of X such that X − S is disconnected. A cutpoint of X is a point p ∈ X such that {p} is a cutset of X. A cutset or cutpoint of X is said to separate X. (Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied. Adams 180-181).

By definition, every point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a cutpoint. Thus $\{\pi\}$ 
is a cutset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. The set $[-1,1]$ is also a cutset as the boundary of the set creates the cutset. However, $(-1,1)$ would not be a cutset. Is this correct?

Also, is $\mathbb{Z}$ also a cutset as it is the union of the integers?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Is $(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)$ connected?

Comment: Generally, there are not many sets that are *not* cutsets in reals.

Comment: So my examples are all cutsets i.e. $\{\pi\}$, $[-1,1]$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $(-1,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only nontrivial subsets of $\mathbb R$ that are not cutsets are rays (open or closed) and unions of two rays. That's because they are precisely the complements of (possibly degenerate) intervals, which are the connected subsets.

Comment: So $(-1,1)$ and $[1,1]$ are not cutsets but $[8,\infty)$ would be?

Comment: @Learner : Wrong way around. Just look at their complements. What remains when you cut them out of the real line? If it's one piece, then the set is not a cutset. If there are two or more pieces, it is a cutset. It's very intuitive. In other words, if removing a set cuts the line into several pieces, then the set you removed is a cutset. Hence the name. Think of drawing the line with a pencil and then erasing the set in question. What's left?

Comment: Makes sense for those. Wouldn't $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$ also cut it into multiple pieces?

Comment: Yes. And since that set is not a ray (or union of two rays), that set is a cutset. Only rays (and unions of two rays) fail to be cutsets. Everything else IS a cutset, so your example is a cutset. In fact, both $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z$ are cutsets, for the same reason. Erase the first, and you get disjoint intervals between successive integers (not connected); erase the second and you get the integers (also not connected).